# makfile variable expansion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a few libs that use each other. Whenever I build any of them I need to define preprocessor define to make sure that proper visibility modifiers are used (e.g. dllimport/dllexport in windows speak).
All the libs use the same makefile, that is, they share rules, CFLAGS etc. All these libs only differ by list of input files, the rest of makefiles are shared by the libs.
The shared makefile has a variable that contains list of all the libs, like this:

```
MODULE_LIBS = liba123 libb456 libc999
```

Then, I need these preprocessor defines to be enabled for each of these libs:

```
For liba123: -Da123_EXPORTS
For libb456: -Db456_EXPORTS
For libc999: -Dc999_EXPORTS
```

Each of these libs live in their respective subfolders that are names like the libs themselves (e.g. liba123, libb456 etc).
So, I wrote this makefile trick to enabled these EXPORTS defines based on the path of the file being compiled:

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) **-D$(filter $(MODULE_LIBS),$(subst lib, ,$(subst /, ,$@)))_EXPORTS**  -c -o $@ $<

I have to add that thing ('-D$(filter $(MODULE_LIBS),$(subst lib, ,$(subst /, ,$@)))_EXPORTS') all over the place, because I have many similar rules. There is nothing can be done with all these different rules, but there is one thing that they have in common: the $(CPPFLAGS).
 Here comes the question. Can I add that "-D$(filter $(MODULE_LIBS),$(subst lib, ,$(subst /, ,$@)))_EXPORTS" to CPPFLAGS in such a way that all these makefile variables would only expand in place where it's used?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do it this way:

```
liba123/%.o : EXPORTS=a123_EXPORTS
libb456/%.o : EXPORTS=b456_EXPORTS
libc999/%.o : EXPORTS=c999_EXPORTS

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -D$(EXPORTS) -c -o $@ $<
```

But you can put them in CPPFLAGS if you prefer:

```
liba123/%.o : CPPFLAGS+=-Da123_EXPORTS
libb456/%.o : CPPFLAGS+=-Db456_EXPORTS
libc999/%.o : CPPFLAGS+=-Dc999_EXPORTS
```

Comment: I think I did it the way i mentioned earlier. I simply had to use *recursive expansion* instead of *simple variable expansion*. That way all the automatics weren't expanded until the rule is executed. The reason I didn't do it the way you mentioned is because the list of modules and makefile is 3rd party product and it's been changing over and over.